# magento - use jalali calendar instead of gregorian

Tags: magento-1.6, date

I want to change the way that dates are shown in magento and use jalali calendar instead.

In order to do that, I want to just edit the parts that are responsible for showing dates and before showing them, change gregorian dates to jalali. and also whenever user is entering any jalali date, I convert them to gregorian before saving in db.

The second part (convert to gregorian before saving) is somehow done. But I got stuck in first part. For example How can I edit the way that dates are shown in "Set Product as New from Date" in Creating product in admin?

any idea is appreciated.

P.S : I ask the same question in stackoverflow too : [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23590555/magento-use-jalali-calendar-instead-of-gregorian)

Comment: Is this for both the `frontend` and the `adminhtml`?

Comment: Actually yes, I need for both part.
But I have problem in **adminhtml** , more than **frontend**